# How do you completely delete an array in C, to the point you can reinitialize it?

Tags: c, arrays

As in: How do you recover the memory, and delete the array to such an extent you can initialize it again later in the program? Like so:

```
char * array[][2] = {
{"bla","bla","bla"},
{"blabity","blabity","bla"}
}
// Delete array
sizeof(array) == NULL;
char * array[][2] = {
{"bla","bla","bla"},
{"blabity","blabity","bla"}
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(array) == NULL`?

Comment: You can't, not exactly like that - a variable is defined in a scope, and once it's defined, it can't be undefined.

Comment: Yeah that `sizeof` thing was just a guess. I'll use `malloc` & `free`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. An array defined using brackets (outside the scope of a function<sup>1</sup>) is compiled directly into your program, and therefore cannot be deallocated. You can, however, reinitialize it simply by writing the initial contents to it again. If you want to be able to create and destroy an array at will, you need to store it as a pointer and use `malloc` and `free`.

<sup>1</sup>: Within a function, the array will be created on the stack each time the function is run, and destroyed when it exits, unless it is defined as a static variable. You still cannot deallocate it without returning.

Comment: How exactly would you `malloc` an array and still be able to set it's values all at once? (Or wouldn't you?)

Comment: @JV You could use `memcpy` with a static array to set the whole thing at once, but other than that you would have to do it separately.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot destroy a statically initialized array, because their lifetime is the lifetime of the whole program. You can trivially allocate more static arrays at any time- there's no need to deallocate your old static data first.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot arbitrarily destroy static and/or function-local objects.

The only objects whose lifetime you can explicitly control are those that are dynamically allocated (e.g. with `malloc`).

Comment: You can easily destroy function-local object.  Just return from the function.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: That is not "arbitrarily".

Answer (score 1):

Use the "malloc family": [`malloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html), [`calloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/calloc.html), [`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html), and [`free()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/free.html).

Don't forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`!